# VBA Error - Object variable or with block variable not set in Worksheet Event

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro set up to add boxes to a chart and link them to tables in two other sheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Declare and assign values to sh1 and sh2
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Training Master")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Attendance Master")




'Declare and assign values to sp1 and sp2
Dim sp1 As Range
Dim sp2 As Range
Set sp1 = sh1.Range("C:C").Find("2nd Process")
Set sp2 = sh2.Range("C:C").Find("2nd Process")

'Adds boxes to organizational chart
Target.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
Target.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDouble
Target.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDouble
Target.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDouble
Target.Offset(1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
Target.Offset(1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDouble
Target.Offset(1).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDouble
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3

'Adds line to table in Training Master, links appropriate cells to 
organizational chart
sp1.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 19).Insert
sp1.Offset(-2, -1).Copy sp1.Offset(-1, -1)
sp1.Offset(-2, 9).Copy sp1.Offset(-1, 9)

'Adds line to table in Attendance Master, returns error 91
sp2.Resize(1, 7).Insert 'Debug identifies this line as error 91
sp2.Offset(-2).Copy sp2.Offset(-1)

End Sub
```

It appears as though every variable has been assigned a value, and I have double and triple checked that the spelling of the sheet names matches the reference in the code. Why am I getting:

> error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Which line? Probably your search term is not found.

Comment: See comments in code, fourth to last line.

Comment: So `sp2` is Nothing and hence the error.

Comment: I highly recommend to use meaningful variable names if you start with `sh1` you will soon end up with `sh23` and lose track. Why don't you just use `wsTraining` and `wsAttendance` instead? You code would really benefit from that, you could easier understand your own code, easier to maintain and as result less errors.

Answer (score 1):

After using the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) always test if find was successfull:

```
Set sp1 = sh1.Range("C:C").Find("2nd Process")

If sp1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "2nd Process was not found in " & sh1.Name
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I highly recommend to **always** specify the `LookAt` parameter for the find method:

- Either `Find(What:="2nd Process", LookAt:=xlWhole)` to find whole cell values,
- Or `Find(What:="2nd Process", LookAt:=xlPart)` to find a part of a cell value.

If you don't specify the `LookAt` parameter Excel will use the one that was used last by either VBA or manual using find. So if you don't specify it you never know which one Excel uses.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to figure out why Find() isn't working. "2nd Process" definitely appears several times in Range("C:C") on my sheet.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Have a look at my edit. It's probably that or that you must specify the other parameters (see also the documentation link I gave). Especially `MatchCase` and `LookIn` parameters might be also of interest and should be specified.

Comment: The C-columns in "Training Master" and "Attendance Master" are identical, and the find function works just fine with the sp1 variable. Naturally, I would suspect it to work just fine for sp2 if I use identical code. Is there any reason why these might be treated differently?

Comment: Any additional spaces or case sensitivity can cause differences. Which parameter did you specify for your find method?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because if `sp1` is nothing, the the `Offest` fails. Change a bit your code to this one to check whether it is "Something" and act correspondingly:

```
'Adds line to table in Training Master, links appropriate cells to
    MsgBox sp1 Is Nothing
If Not sp1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox sp1.Address
    sp1.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 19).Insert
    sp1.Offset(-2, -1).Copy sp1.Offset(-1, -1)
    sp1.Offset(-2, 9).Copy sp1.Offset(-1, 9)
End If
```